# Data validation with dynamic range & Vlookup formula in cell to create semi-automated list

Tags: validation, dynamic, vlookup

I am trying to make a list which is partially automated by vlookup and the user complete the values (from a list) that Vlookup didn't find.
after the list is completed, the values are copied to other Sheet to save the data for analysis.
for example: column A is business names ("McBurger"), Column B is category ("Food") each category is a defined name, and column C is sub-category ("Junk").

Now, Column B (category) has Vlookup in the cell, to find (from other sheet) if the "Mcburger" was already defined as "Food". Column C also have Vlookup in the cell, to find (from the other sheet) if the "Mcburger" was already defined as "Junk" in the subcategory.
If vlookup find the match, it complete the list automatically, if not...the list stays empty and the user need to complete the category and subcategory with dynamic range from a list.
**Column C (subcategory) is a dynamic range of column B(category)**
from what I've tried, when column B (category) is empty, then trying to write the dynamic range in column C, gives error: Data validation in C1 =indirect(B1) because it cannot direct to a blank....

How can i create a list that part of the data that was previously filled, is pulled to the row, and the rest is manually entered by the user. 
Appreciate your help in any direction to solve it, not necessarily in the way i describe above.
Thank you !